# How do you interpret a bit string using sharp snmp lib (hrPrinterDetectedErrorState)?

Tags: powershell, sharp-snmp

How do you interpret hrPrinterDetectedErrorState (http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.2) or something like it using Sharp Snmp lib?  Is there some kind of bit string type?  It's kind of a bitmask, but you may only receive one byte instead of two (or I've seen four bytes).

Comment: Impossible. To interpret BITS the MIB documents are mandatory and only #SNMP Pro has that kind of support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is there some generic #snmp method that converts a multiple byte octetstring into bits (or an integer)?

Comment: `OctetString.GetRaw`.

Comment: GetRaw() returns a byte array.  I was thinking of a single integer.

Comment: bytes are even easier for bit operations.

Comment: In the case of hrPrinterDetectedErrorState, I would have to have 2 [flags] enum's instead of one, because there are 15 bits to test.

Answer (score 1):

Did it on my own in powershell.

```
[flags()] Enum hrPrinterDetectedErrorState
{
  lowPaper            = 0x8000
  noPaper             = 0x4000
  lowToner            = 0x2000
  noToner             = 0x1000
  doorOpen            = 0x0800
  jammed              = 0x0400
  Offline             = 0x0200
  serviceRequested    = 0x0100

  inputTrayMissing    = 0x0080
  outputTrayMissing   = 0x0040
  markerSupplyMissing = 0x0020
  outputNearFull      = 0x0010
  outputFull          = 0x0008
  inputTrayEmpty      = 0x0004
  overduePreventMaint = 0x0002
  notUsed             = 0x0001
}

function snmpmessage($data) {

  $bytes = [byte[]][char[]]$data

  # pack up to two bytes into an int left to right
  $code = [int]$bytes[0]
  $code = $code -shl 8
  if ($bytes[1]) { $code = $code + $bytes[1] }

  [hrPrinterDetectedErrorState]$code

}

PS C:\> snmpmessage -join [char[]](0x91,0x04)
inputTrayEmpty, serviceRequested, noToner, lowPaper
```